# Does the with-as technique work with cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, exception, cx-oracle

In recent versions of python, one can use something like `with open('abc.txt') as f:` to guarantee that the file is closed even if an exception occurs in the following (indented) code block. I was wondering if this technique would also work for cx_Oracle connection objects. For example, could I do something like this to guarantee the database connection gets closed if an error occurred in the subsequent code block:

```
with cx_Oracle.connect('uname/pwd@schema.db') as conn:
  c = conn.Cursor()
  c.execute("Select * from table1")
  #...etc
```

Currently I can accomplish this through the use of try...except...finally, but I prefer the with...as technique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [the `Connection` object can act as a context manager](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me. Connection \__exit__() only commits changes, it doesn't close the connection.

Comment: From the documentation: _The default (but deprecated) behavior is to roll back the transaction in the event of an exception and to commit it otherwise. If the value of cx_Oracle.__future__.ctx_mgr_close _is set to True, however, the connection is closed instead. In cx_Oracle 7, this will become the default behaviour._

Answer (score 4):

Even if the Connection object didn't do it itself (which apparently it does), as long as it provided a `.close()` method it'd be easy to make your own wrapper, using [contextlib.closing](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing)

```
>>> from contextlib import closing
>>> 
>>> class FakeC(object):
...     def close(self):
...         print 'closing!'
...     def execute(self, cmd):
...         print cmd
... 
>>> with closing(FakeC()) as c:
...     c.execute("fred")
...     raise Exception("something went wrong!")
... 
fred
closing!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
Exception: something went wrong!
```

And other variations are almost as easy.

[Wrote the above before the "Yes!" answer was posted and decided to publish it anyway.]